# how to adjust a covariance matrix that is singular when dealing with canonical correlation analysis(CCA)

Tags: covariance, correlation

My question is about the inverse of covariance matrix that is used in CCA (canonical correlation analysis).

Since the answer(i.e. the weights) to the CCA problem is the eigen vector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix **A=$Cov_{XX}^{-1}$ * $Cov_{XY}$*  $Cov_{YY}^{-1}$ *$Cov_{YX}$**, I need the $Cov_{XX}$ and $Cov_{YY}$ be nonsingular.

However, when processing my data,which is related to financial variables, it happens that both of $Cov_{XX}$ and $Cov_{YY}$ are singular.

Therefore, I'd like to ask how to cope with this problem;is there any approximation to $Cov_{XX}^{-1}$?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 Use mathjax for typesetting.

Comment: I believe you will received a better response at cross validated, flagging the post to migrate it there. A common heuristic when things are singular is to add a small scalar multiple of identity matrix.

Comment: Siong Thye Goh: Thank you. Do you mean to add a small value on every diagonal element?

Comment: That's just a suggestion. You might want to check with those who work with CCA.